# NA in ggboxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a boxplot by the following code in R:

```
ggboxplot(diet_long, x = "time", y = "weight", 
          color = "time", palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07","#00AFBB"),
          order = c("Initial", "wk1", "w2","wk3","wk4"),
          ylab = "Weight", xlab = "Time")
```

and my data is in long format, I am unable to produce the data here. Although, this is how I created the dataset from an original dataset in wide format:

```
diet_long <- gather(diet, time, weight, factor_key=TRUE)
```

and here is the plot:

[image: BOXPLOT]

This is what the plot looks like

How can I remove that NA bar?

Comment: Besides, I always prefer to use `fill` instead of `color` for charts like these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `NA` entries for `time` from your data:

```
library(tidyverse)
diet <- diet %>% filter(!is.na(time))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `base R`

```
subset(diet, complete.cases(time))
```